# Listing file names whose size is greater than 5000 KB in a folder to a separate file

Tags: file, memory, cmd, command, filesystems

I need to list file names whose size is greater than 5000 KB in a folder to a separate file.
How can that be achieved?

The below method does list the file names in a separate file but does not solve my problem.

[How to copy a list of file names to text file?](https://superuser.com/questions/395836/how-to-copy-a-list-of-file-names-to-text-file/395838)

Comment: Please see the SO help information about how to ask. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This can be done with a batch file. Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `dir /?`, `for /?`, `pushd /?`, `popd /?`, `goto /?` and `if /?` and read each output help carefully and completely from top of first to bottom of last help page. The first line in batch file is `@echo off`. The second line is `pushd "C:\Folder\Path"` or `pushd "%~dp0"` for folder containing the batch file. The third line is `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B /O-S 2^>nul') do if %%~zI LEQ 5120000 ( goto ExitLoop ) else echo %%I`. The fourth line is `:ExitLoop` and last line `popd`.

Comment: This can be done directly in the Command Prompt, using `Robocopy.exe`, e.g. `(For /F "Tokens=*" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe "C:\Users\Vikky\Documents" Null /L /Min:5120000 /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS /NS 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %~nxG) 1> "C:\Somewhere\MyOutput.txt"`, Just change `"C:\Users\Vikky\Documents"` to your specific source location, and `"C:\Somewhere\MyOutput.txt"` to your specific destination location and file name.

Comment: You could also do it from the Command Prompt, using `WMIC.exe`, e.g. `(For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe DataFile Where "Drive='C:' And Path='\\Users\\Vikky\\Documents\\' And FileSize >= '5120000'" Get Name /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %~nxG) 1> "C:\Somewhere\MyOutput.txt"`. Just replace the `Drive` letter `C:` and `Path` `\\Users\\Vikky\\Documents\\ ` with your specific source drive and path, _(noting the double back slashes)_, and, of course, `"C:\Somewhere\MyOutput.txt"` to your specific destination location and file name.

Comment: Well, the fourth line with the __FOR__ loop should be as follows to write the output file names into a file `(for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B /O-S 2^>nul') do if %%~zI LEQ 5120000 ( goto ExitLoop ) else echo %%I)>"C:\Somewhere\MyOutput.txt"`. But the first solution posted by Compo is better and faster.